# Refreshing data from FireStore GET subscription- Angular - Firebase/FireStore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, ionic4

I am subscribing to Firestore's document "this.afs.collection('messaging').doc(email);" which is located in NgOnInit().  Once I Create another document in Firestore, I want to refresh the data.  I am a little confused on the best way to do this.  I have tried "window.location.reload()" and my POST operation does not follow through.  I have also tried using changeDetector which has not helped as well.

COMPONENT

```
ngOnInit(){
const doc = this.afs.collection('messaging').doc(email);
doc.subscribe( usersData => { this.users = usersData });
```

`

`

TEMPLATE

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users;index as i">
{{user.payload.doc.data().displayName}}
</ng-container>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the pattern I assume you use `@angular/fire`. Plus, you're dealing here with websockets behind the scene meaning that everything that happens here occurs in real-time. Meaning, you don't have to refresh anything.

Comment: incorrect.  My data is not being updated when I post new data. `this.afs.collection('messaging').doc(senderEmail).collection(`messages-${receiverEmail}`).add({
      messages: dataArg.messages,
    });`

Comment: You're not updating the email doc, but creating a new document inside a subcollection that your'e not subscribing to..

Comment: i am subscribed on the second line "doc.subscribe()"